# Can I create a function to switch between two returns every time interval?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm creating a program and i would like to create a function that returns a string from two strings every, let's say, 1 second, so it switches between returning one string to the other. Is there a way to do this in python?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need the function to check the time!

For this you can use the built-in `time.time()` function - this returns the current time in seconds, as a float, since the Epoch.

To make the function change its output every second, you can see if the number of seconds since the Epoch is even. I.e. convert the output of `time.time()` to an integer and check either `t % 2` or `t & 1` - they come to the same thing - the first is checking if there is a remainder when divided by two, the second is checking if the least-significant bit is on - if it is even.

Therefore, something like:

```
import time
def gimme_string():
    if int(time.time()) & 1:
        return 'some string'
    return 'a different string'
```

To test this you can just manually call the function in the interpreter and you can see that the output changes every second (I am calling the function roughly three times per second here).

```
>>> gimme_string()
'a different string'
>>> gimme_string()
'some string'
>>> gimme_string()
'some string'
>>> gimme_string()
'a different string'
>>> gimme_string()
'some string'
>>> gimme_string()
'some string'
>>> gimme_string()
'some string'
>>> gimme_string()
'a different string'
>>> gimme_string()
'a different string'
>>> gimme_string()
'a different string'
>>> gimme_string()
'some string'
>>> gimme_string()
'some string'
>>> gimme_string()
'some string'
>>> gimme_string()
'a different string'
>>> gimme_string()
'a different string'
>>> gimme_string()
'a different string'
>>> gimme_string()
'some string'
>>> gimme_string()
```